# On plugin activation, create page and set template?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin that I want to create a page when it is activated and also set the template that it's using.

I've done the first part in that on activation it creates the page, how can I set the template? This is what I've attempted but it just picks the default template:

```
        if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array( 'contact.php' ) ) ) {
            $template = $theme_file;
        } else {
            $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/contact.php';
        }

        //post status and options
        $post = array(
              'comment_status' => 'closed',
              'ping_status' =>  'closed' ,
              'post_author' => 1,
              'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
              'post_name' => 'Contact',
              'post_status' => 'publish' ,
              'post_title' => 'Contact',
              'post_type' => 'page',
              'page_template' => $template
        );  
        wp_insert_post( $post );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    add_filter( 'page_template', 'wp_page_template' );
    function wp_page_template( $page_template )
    {
        if ( is_page( 'Contact' ) ) {
            $page_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/contact.php';
        }
        return $page_template;
    }
```

try this...